# Airflow Email Backend not being Called

Tags: python, airflow, sendgrid

a bug I have been working on for last 2 days and it has begun to eat me out, after all the debugging and shooting in the dark.

The airflow doesnt seem to even, trigger the mail, I 'll explain how :

this is my airflow.cfg setting :

```
[email]
email_backend = airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp
SENDGRID_MAIL_FROM=<random-email-id@doesntexist.com>
#SENDGRID_API_KEY=...
[smtp]e
smtp_host = smtp.sendgrid.net
smtp_starttls = True
smtp_ssl = False
# Uncomment and set the user/pass settings if you want to use SMTP AUTH
smtp_user = apikey
smtp_password = ...
smtp_port = 465
smtp_mail_from = <random-email-id@doesntexist.com>
```

Then, I see, the file it is referring to is utils/email.py with method : send_email_smtp

```
def send_email(to, subject, html_content, files=None, dryrun=False, cc=None, bcc=None, mime_subtype='mixed'):
    """
    Send email using backend specified in EMAIL_BACKEND.
    """
    path, attr = configuration.get('email', 'EMAIL_BACKEND').rsplit('.', 1)
    module = importlib.import_module(path)
    backend = getattr(module, attr)
    return backend(to, subject, html_content, files=files, dryrun=dryrun, cc=cc, bcc=bcc, mime_subtype=mime_subtype)

def send_email_smtp(to, subject, html_content, files=None, dryrun=False, cc=None, bcc=None, mime_subtype='mixed'):
    """
    Send an email with html content

    >>> send_email('test@example.com', 'foo', '<b>Foo</b> bar', ['/dev/null'], dryrun=True)
    """
    SMTP_MAIL_FROM = configuration.get('smtp', 'SMTP_MAIL_FROM')
    TITU
    to = get_email_address_list(to)
    log.info("!!!!#@Q@$%%%^%!@!@!@!@!@!@!@!@!@!@%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%")
    msg = MIMEMultipart(mime_subtype)
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = SMTP_MAIL_FROM
    msg['To'] = ", ".join(to)
    recipients = to
    if cc:
        cc = get_email_address_list(cc)
        msg['CC'] = ", ".join(cc)
        recipients = recipients + cc

    if bcc:
        # don't add bcc in header
        bcc = get_email_address_list(bcc)
        recipients = recipients + bcc

    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    mime_text = MIMEText(html_content, 'html')
    msg.attach(mime_text)

    for fname in files or []:
        basename = os.path.basename(fname)
        with open(fname, "rb") as f:
            part = MIMEApplication(
                f.read(),
                Name=basename
            )
            part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % basename
            part['Content-ID'] = '<%s>' % basename
            msg.attach(part)
    #send_MIME_email(SMTP_MAIL_FROM, recipients, msg, dryrun)
    send_MIME_email_sendgrid(SMTP_MAIL_FROM, recipients, msg, dryrun)

def send_MIME_email_sendgrid(e_from, e_to, mime_msg, dryrun=False):
    log = LoggingMixin().log
    sg = SendGridAPIClient('..<my-sendgrid-key>..')
    sg.send(mime_msg)
    log.info("Sent an alert email to %s", e_to)
```

Even the 'log.info('!#!@$#@%@%') isnt getting logged above.

Please help. really couldnt get this right - I am using Airflow 1.9.0 with sendgrid installed on top of it - Airflow 1.10.0 and below doesnt come with sendgrid dependency by default I guess

Comment: sendgrid API key is correct and working, tested otherwise. the email Id above doesnt exist, it is random one. but with sendgrid, I could send mails over

Comment: I installed 1.10.1 now., but things in vain. why I am not taking up the latest airflow version is because of dependency on sql server as my backend.

Comment: I found out,that 'on_failure_callback' and 'on_success_callback' need to be set in the tasks, and atleast the email backend is being called.
However, now, from within airflow, I get the following error:
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

Answer (score 0):

this was being called, indeed.
what we need is two-folds:

specify the task as :

```
email_on_failure=True,
email=['i.wont@tell.com']
```

and our problem was on authenticating with sendgrid the service user we running airflow webserver/scheduler from.